# Test Spring Mvc controller and inject static class

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit

The following code is the standard method to write a JUnit test for a Mvc controller.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ApplicationTestCassandra.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class TestControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testupTimeStart() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/uptime"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

    }
}
```

This works fine, but I would like to replace an autowired class with a special class for testing. The class CassandraSimpleConnection is injected via @Autowired in my controller.
I have tried several approaches, but no luck.
The following code fails because of an Mvc 404 error, because I guess my application with the REST interface is not running at all.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
//ApplicationTestCassandra is SpringBoot application startpoint class with @SpringBootApplication annotation
//@ContextConfiguration(classes = ApplicationTestCassandra.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class)//, classes = {ApplicationTestCassandra.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class TestControllerTests {

    @Service
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan(basePackages={"blabla.functionalTests"})
    static class CassandraSimpleConnection {

        public Metadata testConnection(TestConfiguration configuration) {
            Metadata metadata = null;
            // return metadata;

            throw new RuntimeException("Could not connect to any server");
        }
    }
```

If I use

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class,    classes = {ApplicationTestCassandra.class})
```

CassandraSimpleConnection is not replaced with my static class.

Could somebody help me please? The documentation about the annotations is quite confusing.

Comment: And why should it. It is a service not a configuration so it will never be detected. Also adding `@EnableWebMvc` and `@ComponentScan` on a non `@Configuration` class is pretty useless.

Comment: Ok, thanks. How can I replace a service class, when running a test? What is the simplest way to mock CassandraSimpleConnection? Should I rather mock com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster?

Comment: You can use @Bean for  CassandraSimpleConnection  for 'overriding' your bean in the test case

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the comments and here is the solution:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { MyApplication.class })
public class MyTests {

        @MockBean
        private MyBeanClass myTestBean;

        @Before
        public void setup() {
             ...
             when(myTestBean.doSomething()).thenReturn(someResult);
        }

        @Test
        public void test() {
             // MyBeanClass bean is replaced with myTestBean in the ApplicationContext here
        }
}
```